# writing a bilingual article

Tags: teaching

Thanks but what if I write an article in English and use some quotations in Turkish since my intended readers are bilingual; that is Turkish and English?

I refer to Ms Clare Hopping's Bilingual Wordsmiths: The Challenges of Writing in Two Languages

Comment: I think you should edit your post so that it does not look like second part of another question.

Comment: Also, what is your question? What information do you seek?

Comment: "What if I write an article in English and use some quotations in Turkish?" is not an answerable question.

Answer (score 1):

Stick to English for the entirety of the article if you are publishing it to a journal, website, where the primary language is English for both its content (and if not more importantly) its readers. If you quote Turkish (or any other language for that matter) make sure that you provide an English translation.

Just because your intended readers are bilingual, doesn't mean that they all have the same level of competency in both languages to understand both fluently. Provide a common means by which those with less skill can understand your quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If the intended reader can reasonably be presumed to be fluent in both languages, then no translation should be necessary.

I work with literature in three modern Romance languages with texts that are modern to medieval.  I do **not** provide translations for Spanish or Portuguese when I write in English, and only provide them for Asturian where the meaning of the quote is not clear from the perspective of a modern Spanish or Portuguese speaker.  I do not generally expect to see translations generally when I see quotations in French or Italian, and if the article is on medieval literature, I do not expect to see translations for Latin, but I do generally expect it for Latin in articles on modern literature and for Romanian in general, and anytime there is a finer language distinction (for example, comparing two words that would be translated similarly into English).  For other regional/minority languages, the practice is similar to what I do with Asturian — if they can be reasonably understood without potential for misunderstanding, no translation necessary, but otherwise, translations are provided.

The editor that you work with will make the final say, of course.  If they feel translations are necessary for the journal's audience, then they will request translations.  Likewise, if you already provide translations and they don't think they are necessary, then they will recommend removing them before publishing.